# Android OpenGL2.0 renderer scaling to resolution properly

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm drawing on Android with coordinates between -1.0 and 1.0, but the renderer is mapping these coordinates to the wrong places. In landscape, the width doesn't extend to the corners, and in portrait, the width extends over the screen borders slightly. I'm trying to make this fill the screen resolution. Here's my code:

```
package com.mycompany.brickbreaker;

import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.util.Log;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    private BrickBreaker game;

    public MyGLRenderer(BrickBreaker activity) {
        super();
        game = activity;
    }

    //mMVPMatrix stands for "Model View Projection Matrix"
    private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
        //Set the background frame color
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused){
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        //Set the camera position (View Matrix)
        Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0f);

        //Calculate the projection and view transformation
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);

        //Draw the rectangle!
        game.draw(mMVPMatrix);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height){

        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        Log.d("Touch", "Surface changed at height/width " + height + "/" + width);
        float ratio = (float) width/(float) height;

        //This projection matrix is applied to object coordinates in
        //the onDrawFrame() method
        Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);
    }

    public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){
        //create the shader type
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

        //add the code to the shader, and compile it
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

        return shader;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to draw with coordinates between -1.0 and 1.0, why are you using view and projection matrices? That's exactly the range you get by default, without **any** view or projection matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert at openGL, but I do have a working engine.

In your on SurfaceChanged, you pass in the old projectionMatrix.

You should add the following code:

```
//Clear the matricies
    for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        mProjectionMatrix[i] = 0.0f;
        mViewMatrix[i] = 0.0f;
        mMVPMatrix[i] = 0.0f;
    }

    // Setup our screen width and height for normal sprite translation.
    Matrix.orthoM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, 0f, width, 0.0f, height, 0, 50);

    // Set the camera position (View matrix)
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    // Calculate the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);
```

Hopefully that fixes your problem.

Comment: Although clearing the matrix is a good idea I hadn't thought of, this still doesn't seem to change anything :(. What exactly does orthoM change? And should I add it anywhere other than onSurfaceChanged?

Answer (score 0):

So I've solved this. What was going on is that when your projection matrix is created with Matrix.frustumM(0,0,-ratio,ratio....), the openGl grid is actually changed from a -1 to 1 range in both X and Y, into a -1 to 1 grid in the y, with a -ratio to ratio range in x coordinates. Multiplying any x-coordinates I used by the ratio passed to frustumM made everything happy again.

Comment: That's really much more convoluted than it needs to be. Like I said in the comment above, it's far easier to not apply a transformation at all if you  have coordinates that are already in the default OpenGL coordinate system.